# configuring subdirectory app in nginx

Tags: nginx

Can someone help me configure my nginx where:

/app -> is the local html pages

/    -> is the https server which does not have app folder

The following conf didnt work for me: (

```
server {
    listen              80;
    ssl_verify_client   off;
    server_name         localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass        https://xx.xx.xx.xx/;
    }
    location /app {
      root "c:\LOCAL_PATH\app";
      index  index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you routing the https requests to the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Exhanging your `location /`-block for the following oughta do it:

```
location / { rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri?; }
```

Comment: this doesn't work. in fact / root now redirects to the ip address

Comment: As I understood the question you want everything in the `/app`-path to be served locally (your `location /app`-block does that) and everything else should be served by (and thus redirected to)the https server (which is what the rewrite does). Am I misunderstanding what you want completely here?